# Calculations with vectors - scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Let $x,y,v$ be vectors with $v\cdot v=1$.

Then we have that \begin{align*}\left [x-2(x\cdot v)v\right ]\cdot \left [y-2(y\cdot v)v\right ]&=x\cdot y-2(x\cdot v)(y\cdot v)-2(x\cdot v)(y\cdot v)+4(x\cdot v)(y\cdot v)(v\cdot v) \\ & = x\cdot y-4(x\cdot v)(y\cdot v)+4(x\cdot v)(y\cdot v) \\ & = x\cdot y\end{align*}
Would it be correct to do the following instead?
\begin{align*}\left [x-2(x\cdot v)v\right ]\cdot \left [y-2(y\cdot v)v\right ]&=\left (x-2x\cdot v^2\right )\cdot \left (y-2y\cdot v^2\right )\\ &=\left (x-2x\right )\cdot \left (y-2y\right ) \\ &=\left (-x\right )\cdot \left (-y\right ) \\ & = x\cdot y\end{align*}

Comment: How are you defining $v^2$? $(x\cdot v)v\neq x\cdot v^2$ if you mean $v^2=v\cdot v$

Comment: So the first way is the correct one, right? @FShrike

Comment: As it stands, the second way is meaningless, since $(x\cdot v)v\neq x\cdot(v\cdot v)$, since the dot product returns a scalar, not a vector. The first way is correct as far as I can tell

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @FShrike